# Stable Matching Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, match, matching, discrete-mathematics, stable-marriage

I was reading up on the stable marriage problem and chanced upon this question: Is it possible that a man1 has woman1 on the top of his preference list, and woman1 has man1 on top of hers, but still there exists a stable matching (not necessarily man optimal or woman optimal) where they are not paired together?

Comment: what order are pairs matched in? i think either may get "claimed" (put in a marriage with non-optimal mate) if the ordering of the pairings allows for that to happen

Comment: Reread the definition of a stable matching. You'll find that the answer to your question follows immediately from the definition.

Comment: this is not really a programming problem, by the way. maybe on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ or another SE forum, but i like the question!  I also realize now that i am not too familiar with this particular problem and didn't realize there's a tag for it on SO, so maybe don't listen to me ;)

Comment: Actually from the definition it sounds like she's asking are there some solutions that are stable but not strongly stable

Answer (score 0):

The case you are describing sounds like one that is stable but not strongly stable.

From "The structure of stable marriage with indifference":
A matching M is strongly stable if there is no couple (x,y) such that x strictly prefers y to his/her partner in M, and y either strictly prefers x to his/her partner ...
For a given instance I of SMP, the existence of a weakly stable matching is guaranteed: ...
On the other hand, it is straightforward to construct instances of SMT which admit no strongly stable matching.

So it sounds like the answer is yes... it is possible.